# Ошибка при создании MVC

Tags: php, mvc

Здравствуйте, в чем может быть ошибка. PHPStorm ругается на 2-ую строчку
и выводит:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Failed to
>   include class: Config' in C:\xampp\htdocs\MY_MVC\lib\init.php:21 Stack
>   trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\MY_MVC\config\config.php(3):
>   __autoload('Config') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\MY_MVC\lib\init.php(3): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MY_MVC\webroot\index.php(6):
>   require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MY_MVC\lib\init.php on line 21

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дайте более полное описание проблемы. В частности, что за фреймворк используется или это самопись?

Comment: Не может подключить класс через автолоад. Видимо путь не правильно прописан

Comment: Вы уверены что это PhpStorm ругается? Ошибка явно php интерпретатора

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Спасибо, всем что откликнулись. Проблема решена, пропустил одну букву в переменной